# Ghostscript Error limitcheck when convert EPS to PNG

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I need to use ghostscript to programmatically convert EPS files to PNG.
The ghostscript command is:

`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dEPSCrop -r300 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=tmp.png input.eps`

The problem is: some of the EPS files cause error:

```
Error: /limitcheck in --shfill--
Operand stack:
   --dict:6/6(L)--   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   shfill   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   shfill   shfill   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1972   1   3   %oparray_pop   shfill   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   shfill   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   shfill   1940   1   10   %oparray_pop   shfill   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:730/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:92/200(L)--   --dict:57/75(L)--   --dict:211/313(L)--   --dict:72/140(L)--   --dict:0/10(G)--   --dict:0/10(L)--   --dict:0/50(ro)(G)--   --dict:57/71(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 4781076
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

From what I gathered, it looks like the vector file is too complex that it hits some ghostscript's limits. Is there some parameters I can change that can lift such limits? Or the only way is to edit the file to be less complex, or manually export from Illustrator?

Comment: Are you sure you're not encountering a Postscript limit? *Generally* Postscript has harder limits than Ghostscript. Anyway, it's pretty much impossible to guess without seeing the file.

Comment: It could be PostScript limit. Is there some way I can find out what limit it is? And is it possible to lift the limit? I can upload the file if it helps. @chrisl

Comment: most PS limits are documented in the PLRM. If you put the file somewhere accessible (dropbox or similar), I can take a look at it - I can't promise a solution, though!

Comment: So.... you're definitely hitting an implementation limit. Basically, in the interest of speed, gs does as much of the low level rendering calculations in fixed point arithmetic (rather than floating point). And this file ends up trying to use a set of values that simply don't fit in the fixed point representation. Looking at the content of the file, it looks like there are various places where it scales up by a factor of 66244029756818.164 - so not surprising it overflows!

Comment: (Continued).... Having said that, both the other Postscript interpreters/renderers I have access to also throw errors running the file. If you can narrow it down to one shading that causes the error (rather than the over 165 instances that are in the file!), then it would be worth opening a bug at https://bugs.ghostscript.com/ and seeing if we can do *something* about it......

Comment: (Continued 2).... In the meantime, strictly as a workaround(!!), you can convert the eps to a PDF ( -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o err.pdf err.eps ) and the into a "new" eps (-sDEVICE=eps2write -o err_new.eps err.pdf ) should get you a "working" file (I believe pdfwrite sanitises the values in some way). The downside is, as the name suggests, eps2write writes Level 2 Postscript, and shfill is a Level 3 feature, so the shadings end up as sampled images, and the file ends up rather large (65Mb). But it should look correct.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: @chrisl Thank you so much! That's a lot more info than I can find on google :D I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, the going to PDF and back to EPS suggestion is not a "solution", it's a workaround for this *specific* problem. In general, round-tripping like that can cause other problems to arise - especially (but not only!) when certain kinds of text are involved.

Comment: Despite that it would be helpful to see the file in question, you could at least show some code around the error position. When using GNU Emacs (for example) you could navigate to the error using "C-u <byte position> C-f" (if you don't know what that means, see the Emacs tutorial, or try it with your favorite editor).